# Pandas concatenate all members of a column with a constant string

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

So I am trying to take all of the members of a Pandas Dataframe Column and add the string `EQUITY`
to them (there is a space before equity). Right now this is what I have:

```
response_score_factors["ULT_PARENT_TICKER_EXCHANGE"] = response_score_factors["ULT_PARENT_TICKER_EXCHANGE"].str.cat(" EQUITY")
```

This is the error I am getting:
    raise ValueError("Did you mean to supply a `sep` keyword?")
ValueError: Did you mean to supply a `sep` keyword? To my knowledge sep would not concatenate the last string so I am not using that. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can just use the `+` operator:

```py
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'x': ['a', 'b', 'c']})
>>> df['x'] + ' EQUITY'
0    a EQUITY
1    b EQUITY
2    c EQUITY
Name: x, dtype: object
```